# Intersection of networking and virtualization?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a question about networking and virtualization which was marked off-topic: [Why aren't packets being passed along Linux bridge to a container?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53062/why-arent-packets-being-passed-along-linux-bridge-to-a-container).

If it was purely about virtualization, sure, Server Fault would be the right place to go.

If it was purely about networking, then presumably it should stay right here.

But it's not. It's about packets traversing virtual network interfaces. It's a question about virtualized networking. So... should I move it to Server Fault? Or is Network Engineering the best place?

Comment: This meta question is actually a duplicate of [another meta question](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/405/8499).

Comment: You question probably belongs on [sf], assuming it is a business network. For a personal network, it would be closed on [sf], and it should probably be asked on [su]. Since it is Linux, you could try to ask it on [unix.se], or one of the Linux OS-specific sites, e.g. [ubuntu.se].