# Regarding questions about Cisco IOU (and other pirated software)

Tags: discussion

Can someome delete my account from Network engineering?  I don't like my IOU question being closed.

PS: please make sure you delete all the Dynamips related Q&A . 
That is a software that Cisco tolerated for years... but since you're so legalistic, please make sure all your users who post questions here about Dynamips have license for an IOS

Comment: and yeah please vote down my posts :-) OMG ...

Answer (score 3):

Let's step back from the [rage quit](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ragequit) button for a moment...

1. [You asked](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/revisions/16544/1) about how to use IOU, which is an internal Cisco tool; this tool has *no valid use case outside of Cisco Systems*.  If you are a Cisco employee, you'd have much better success using Cisco's internal mailing lists, because we cannot offer any IOU support.  However, it's quite clear that you don't work for Cisco.  Thus you're [asking about using pirated software](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15617/160519), which [the community overwhelmingly voted off-topic](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25/775), and Stack Exchange deletes.
2. Regarding your IOU question being deleted, we have dealt with the IOU issue previously.  Early in this site's existence, we also closed and deleted [another IOU question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2210/iou-switch-connectivity-with-real-network) for exactly the same reasons.  Furthermore, the deletion was done by [one of the Community Moderators](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/31/shog9), so I don't think my deletion of [your question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/revisions/16544/1) was without precedent.
3. If you need high-quality Cisco IOS simulation, use [Cisco VIRL](http://virl.cisco.com/) instead of IOU.
4. I do not agree that Dynamips questions are in the same category as IOU.  If you disagree, that sounds like a discussion for another day.
5. If you want to delete your account, you can do so by following the help center links: [help center > How do I delete my account?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account)

*EDIT*:

After the initial discussion in meta, I reworded your question to focus on ioulive86, which is not Cisco IOU; however, I left the question deleted since the only valid use case is pirated software (i.e. IOU).  The community [frowns on those questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15617/160519) and encourages deletion.

In case there is any question about the exchange the started this, I'll post a screen capture of the original comments..

[image: IOU comments]

Comment: I assure you that [this guy](http://tinyurl.com/mljjnyd) does not and did  not work for Cisco. Yet although he is a prominent network guy he can afford to speak about IOU. The GNS3 site abounds in references about IOU. The topic is not a tabu on Cisco hosted forums, the threads are not closed or deleted there.
I did not ask you if you agree or not about the Dynamips thinkg. I could not care less. I just told you.

Comment: BTW I asked how you use ioulive86 to connect IOU not how to use IOU itself. So even in that respect you are wrong.Don't be mad, next time you will do better

Comment: There was no mention of ioulive86, you asked for a "liveiou86 solution" (the only google hit for liveiou86 was your question).  Quoting your first sentence: "How do I connect IOU to a tap interface?"  When I asked "What is IOU?  You mean Cisco's internal IOS emulator?", your response was "Yes".  Forgive my confusion for believing what you asked for, and then confirmed in comments.  Since I don't [traffic in pirated software](http://evilrouters.net/2011/11/01/iou-license-generator-on-github/), I didn't catch the distinctions between liveiou86, ioulive86, and ioulive.

Comment: @user2059078, just because Cisco has turned a blind eye to the issue *so far*, doesn't make unlicensed use of their software legal. Maybe Cisco will never enforce their rights in this regard, but the simple act of not distributing it themselves makes the use of the software clearly unauthorized. SE and the community does not want to see SE entangled in any sort of legal issues that could be avoided and as such pirated software and other illegal activities are frowned upon and removed when found. You have been provided the link on how to delete your account, it requires nothing from us.